# Youtube API: get all playlists created by a specific user?

Tags: youtube-api, playlist

I am trying to work out of the Youtube API offers a method for listing all playlists created by a specific user.

Let's for example say I'd like to get a list of all playlists created by user Nike.
(I am not associated with Nike in any way, and I picked Nike purely as example)

The playlist overview page of user Nike is here: 
https://www.youtube.com/user/nike/playlists
It shows a bunch of playlists. Some are ungrouped and get listed under "Created playlists" others playlists are grouped in ie "At-Home Exercised", "At-Home Nutrition" or "Series".

See screenshot below:

[image: screenshot of youtube playlist page for nike]

I know how I can list all videos in a playlist by playlist ID... but how can I programmatically using the Youtube API (V3) retrieve all these playlists IDs created by userid ('Nike')?